# Downloading Files From S3 To Users Computer

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I have the following view in my Django project

```
class download_mscore_software(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        session = boto3.Session(
            aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        )
        s3 = session.resource('s3')

        clancy = s3.Bucket("magpie-bixly-test").download_file("Clancy-Gorillaz.jpg", "Clancy-Gorillaz.jpg")
```

This works to download the file into my project directory.  However, I need the file to download to the users computer.  How do I change this so that this happens?  I tried this:

```
clancy = s3.Bucket('magpie-bixly-test').download_file('Clancy-Gorillaz.jpg', 'Users/Downloads/Clancy-Gorillaz.jpg')
```

but I get an error saying that there is no such directory.  The same happens if I leave the file name off the end like this.

```
clancy = s3.Bucket('magpie-bixly-test').download_file('Clancy-Gorillaz.jpg', 'Users/Downloads')
```

Comment: Does setting the download location to '/Users/Downloads/Clancy-Gorillaz.jpg' work?

Comment: I believe that is what I tried in my attempted solution 2nd from the bottom.  Unless you mean there is a way to specify the download location other than the ways that I have tried here.

Comment: I mean you should try a leading '/' before 'Users'

Comment: Yes, actually it was a combination of this and mtzd's answer.  I ended up needing the / before Users and also forgot to include the username part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the specified paths are relative to your project and thus the `Users/Downloads` folder isn’t found. You can try specifying the absolute path (Windows: `C:/Users/<USERNAME>/Downloads/Clancy-Gorillaz.jpg` or Linux: `/home/<USERNAME>/Downloads/Clancy-Gorillaz.jpg`). Where `<USERNAME>` should be replaced with the OS user.

Even if it works a good practice is to use [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) to work with a particular OS.

Comment: This solution worked!  Now I just have to figure out how to have it automatically find the location on the users computer instead of hardcoding it but I'm guessing os.path will help with that.  Thank you!